# specify a range value in \SI?

Tags: siunitx

I like to print something like *10-20 cm* using \SI option. I have tried
\SI{10-20}{\cm} which is giving error. How to write it properly?

Comment: IIRC, the correct way of typesetting ranges according to the guidelines of the SI is to include the unit for both numbers, so instead of 10-20 cm you should use 10cm - 20cm.

Comment: **10 cm to 20 cm.** BIPM says: 
The numerical value always precedes the unit and a space is always used to separate the unit from the number. Thus the value of the quantity is the product of the number and the unit. The space between the number and the unit is regarded as a multiplication sign (just as a space between units implies multiplication). The only exceptions to this rule are for the unit symbols for degree, minute and second for plane angle, °, ′ and ″, respectively, for which no space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol. www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct command in recent versions of `siunitx` is `\qtyrange`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\qtyrange{10}{20}{\centi\metre}
\end{document}
```

This will result in

[image]

Just like in [@Bernard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619675/117050) you can change the used phrase to an en-dash using `range-phrase` (for which I'd add non-breaking spaces using `~`):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\qtyrange[range-phrase=~--~]{10}{20}{\cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Problem: This looks like a minus and I'd say the result is -10 cm.

Comment: OK, \qtyrange{10}{20}{\centi\metre} is looking decent. Thank you.

Comment: @Bukaida of course you don't have to type `\centi\metre` everytime, `\cm` will work just as fine (and `siunitx` is smart enough to also parse `\qtyrange{10}{20}{cm}` correctly, but I'd prefer using `\cm` if you have to be short).

Comment: @Skillmon On the 'to do' list is to parse `cm` to `\centi\metre` to allow manipulation ;)

Comment: Just wanted to add that in less recent versions, the equivalent command is `\SIrange`. (Yes, I should update from TL 2020...)

Answer (score 7):

Use `\numrange[range-phrase=--]{10}{20}\,\unit{\cm}͵`.

Comment: @Skillmon: You're right. I'll add it instantly. Thanks!

Comment: I've added code highlighting to your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all. On my system, it didn't yield exactly the expected result for some reason.